# WPF Treeview with fullrow selection and animation

Tags: wpf, treeview

I would like to imitate the Treeview-Control in OSX-Mail with a WPF Treeview and have no idea how to start.
On the screenshots "MAILBOXES" and "SMART MAILBOXES" are folders. Hover the Mouse over each folder fades a "Show" or "Hide" Button in. Clicking on that button slides out the childs ("Inbox","Send" and "Today" at the screenshot).
How can I get something simular using WPF? Is a treeview a good choice to start with?

Thanks a lot!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvL0Y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Usually generic questions like this are not answered on StackOverflow.  I'll give it a shot, but I only have time to provide an outline of what you can do.

It's been my experience to avoid the TreeView at all costs.  It just doesn't behave logically and when searching for nodes it's expensive.

I think you can get the behavior you want by using an **ItemsControl** where the **ItemTemplate** is an **Expander** control.  The **ItemsControl** is bound to a collection of objects that represents your folders.

You can then **DataTemplate** the header of the **Expander** to mimic the hover behavior.  The header would be two **TextBlocks**.  One to identify the expander, i.e. "MAILBOXES" and the other is for the "Show"/"Hide" label.

Essentially, the "Show" and "Hide" is one TextBlock where the text is set by a **DataTrigger** attached to the **IsExpanded** property of the **Expander**.  If **IsExpanded** is true, set the Text to "Hide", if false set it to "Show".

Then for the rest of your items located in each folder, you can put an **ItemsControl** or a **ListBox** inside the **Expander**.  Bind the **ItemsControl** or **ListBox ItemsSource** to the items in each folder.  You can then use the corresponding **ItemTemplate** to design those items however you choose.